# How to stick an embedded document in a specific cell of an excel

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-2010

I have embedded few documents in my excel sheet, into some specific cells. When I apply some filter, or re-size the size of any other row in the spreadsheet, these embedded documents tend to move from its cell.

It is pretty annoying to re-arrange them. Is there any way to make these documents stick in specific cells and to make sure they stay their no matter any kind of formatting that is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the documents (you can use the "Select Objects" functionality in the Home tabs "Find&Select" dropdown if you have a lot:

   [image])
2. Go to the "Format Object..." dialog (right mouse click on any document - or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>)
3. In the "Properties" tab, select "Move and size with cells": [image]

Done!

Comment: Can you please help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655807/how-to-stop-the-resizing-and-moving-of-embedded-objects-in-excel-sheet